# How can I remove issue reference

Tags: github

1. I have `issue #1` and `issue #2` on github.
2. I commenting on the `issue #1` smthing like this: **"I think that
   issue #2 is associated with this issue"**.
3. Now in comments of `issue #2` the message about referencing `issue
   #2` with `issue #1` appears.
4. I delete my comment on `issue #1`.
5. The message about referencing `issue #2` with `issue #1` still
   exists in `issue #2` comments.

**How I can remove the message about referencing from `issue #2` comments?**

Answer (score 20):

It's currently not possible to remove a GitHub Issue reference after it has been created.

Comment: I'm really surprised that this hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Still no solution?.. If so - this functionality is not considered as 'to be fixed'. But what the reason to forbid remove links then? Any ideas?

Comment: It's 2023, and still no solution?

Answer (score -3):

you can edit the commit message:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages

Comment: You didn't quite understand me. I have reformulated the question.

Comment: re-reading your updated question, i believe this is a github bug. i would email the support staff about it. https://help.github.com/contact

Comment: So, if you have already reported the bug. Please, keep us updated.

Comment: i have not reported it. i suggested that you do it. :D

Comment: @Brenden what link do you want to get?

Comment: @Flyte there is no public issue tracker on github.

Comment: @haslo "we will take this into account"